# Threading error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.Prepare" with Android

Tags: android

I am currently developing an Android app where I need to perform a method inside a thread. I have the following code in order to create the thread and perform the

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
      @Override
      public void run() {
          new DownloadSync(getApplicationContext());
      }
}).start();
```

When I try to run this code it displays the error message in the log cat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.Prepare().

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  Your situation is the reason for its existence.  Also, read up on [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) (which is mostly using AsyncTask).

The issue with your code is that something is trying to use a `Handler` internally in your new Thread, but nothing has told the `Looper` to prepare.

Comment: I suppose the Looper would be created by the Activity itself, but the thread is being ran prematurely. Also it's handling UI from that thread, not the UI one, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I had an earlier answer that was not very helpful - I've removed it and kept the relevant bit:

Make sure your DownLoadSync object only communicates with the main UI thread via a handler (if you want to avoid using an AsyncTask)
Declare a runnable and a handler as shown:

```
final Runnable updateMainUIThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Communicating with the main thread!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };


private final Handler handler = new Handler();`
```

And use it like this:
    `handler.post(updateMainUIThread);`

Comment: Your remark about the same piece of code as the declaration makes no sense. The declaration results in a compiled anonymous class. Calling start() on the temporary reference returned by new is totally ok.

Comment: True, but it's horrible and messy. The real answer is in the last line. In fact, I'm starting to avoid anon inner classes altogether because they look like a dogs breakfast (and are hard to follow)